# AutoHotKey script not working with Hudson

Tags: scripting, automation, hudson, autohotkey

I have an AutoHotKey script that basically opens up a few programs, runs a few tests, takes screenshots and saves them to a directory. The script is working flawlessly when running on the machine that has Hudson on it. I have also converted the script to a .exe. I have tried as both logged in and not and have Hudson running as a service. However when the .exe is called through Hudson it does not save the screenshots. Is there something I am missing here? Hoping this has an easy fix.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're saving the screenshots without seeing the code, but are you specifying a full path when saving them? With Hudson do you have to maybe specify a working directory when launching a program?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with Windows Services. Can you find a work-around? It would seem that you could easily perform this without Hudson anyway.